# Converting a file read VB code to c#

Tags: c#, vb6-migration

I need to convert a piece of code from VB to C#. what should I use in place of FileSystemObject and TextStream?

what the below code does is that it reads a file already present in a directory and adds the content of the file to the fields.

```
Private Sub Read_abc_File()
    Dim FileSystem As FileSystemObject
    Dim abcFile As TextStream
    Dim abcLine As String, abcSection As String
    Dim abcFilename As String
    Const Read As Integer = 1

    abcFilename = "abc.txt"


    Set FileSystem = New FileSystemObject

    If Not FileSystem.FileExists(abcFilename) Then
        FileSystem = Null
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set abcFile = FileSystem.OpenTextFile(abcFilename, Read, False)

    Do While abcFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
        abcLine = abcFile.ReadLine

        If abcLine > " " Then
            If Left$(abcLine, 1) = "[" Then
                abcSection = abcLine
            Else
                Select Case abcSection
                    Case "[Datafiles]"
                        DataFilename.AddItem abcLine
                    Case "[Locations]"
                        Location.AddItem abcLine
                    Case "[Formats]"
                        Format.AddItem abcLine
                    Case "[Categories]"
                        Category.AddItem abcLine
                End Select
            End If
        End If            
    Loop

    abcFile.Close
    Set abcFile = Nothing
    Set FileSystem = Nothing
End Sub
```

any suggestions/answers are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: this does not seem like VB.NET code. If this is VB6 code, add a `VB6` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a code snippet to get you started, i think you should be able to complete the job.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fileName = "abc.txt";

    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        return;

    using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```